# Autofac RegisterAssemblyTypes multiple times

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have WPF application with multiple view models and a corresponding class hierarchy. Now I use Autofac as IoC framework. My structure looks simplified like this:

```
public class ViewModelBase 
{}

public class ToolItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{}

public class DocumentItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{}

// Concrete implementations

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{}

public class EditorProperties : ToolItemViewModel
{}

public class TextViewModel : DocumentItemViewModel
{}

// Now in order to do something like this:

var mainViewModel = _scope.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
var tools = _scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<ToolItemViewModel>>();
var documents = _scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<DocumentItemViewModel>>();

// It seems I have to do the following registrations

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(App).Assembly).
    Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<ViewModelBase>()).AsSelf();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(App).Assembly).
    Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ToolItemViewModel))).As<ToolItemViewModel>();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(App).Assembly).
    Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<DocumentItemViewModel>()).AsSelf().
    Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DocumentItemViewModel))).As<DocumentItemViewModel>();
```

Can I avoid running "RegisterAssemblyTypes" multiple times here? All class are derived from ViewModelBase, so I thought one "RegisterAssemblyTypes" could be enough?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot. Autofac requires multiple invocations for each type (i have also posted the link):

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html

Scanning for Types
Otherwise known as convention-driven registration or scanning, Autofac can register a set of types from an assembly according to user-specified rules:

```
var dataAccess = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
   .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Each RegisterAssemblyTypes() call will apply one set of rules only - multiple invocations of RegisterAssemblyTypes() are necessary if there are multiple different sets of components to register.